# Delete values from a sorted vector

Tags: r, date-sorting

I have a vector of 100 sorted values

```
x=rnorm(100)
x_sort=sort(x)
```

How can I delete 2.5% (for example) from upper un lower side of `x_sort`?

Comment: It will be difficult in this case to remove exactly 2.5 %

Comment: let's say 5% or 10 % whatever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
m <- 5 # percentage to be deleted from each side
l <- length(x_sort)
n <- l * m/100
y <- head(tail(x_sort, l - n), l - n*2)

length(x_sort)
#[1] 100
length(y)
#[1] 90
```

You could round the value of `n` to integers or use `floor` or `ceiling` functions, e.g. `n <- round(l * m/100)` to ensure that you're not trying to remove for example 2.3 elements of x.

Another approach:

```
m <- 5 # percentage to be deleted from each side
l <- length(x_sort)
n <- round(l * m/100)
y2 <- x_sort[seq.int(n+1L, l-n, 1L)]
```

Do they return the same?

```
all.equal(y, y2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `quantile` is a way:

```
x=rnorm(100)
x_sort=sort(x)

x_sort2 <- x_sort[ x_sort > quantile(x_sort,0.025) & x_sort < quantile(x_sort,0.975)]
#x_sort2 will be a subset of x_sort starting from the 2.5th quantile and finishing at the 97.5th on this occassion. 
#in bigger datasets it's extremely accurate (now you only have 100 values and you cannot pick the 2.5th for example).      

> length(x_sort)
[1] 100
> length(x_sort2)
[1] 94
```

You can replace 0.025 or 0.975 with exactly the values you want to be your lower or your upper limit and even add a function to do that for you.

Something like this maybe:

```
excluder <- function(myvec,a,b)  { myvec[myvec > quantile(myvec,a) & myvec < quantile(myvec,b)] }
#with myvec being your vector, a the lower limit and b the upper limit    

x_sort3 <- excluder(x_sort,0.025,0.975) 

> length(x_sort3)
[1] 94
```